# understanding typescript type assertion

Tags: typescript

I am just going through a TypeScript tutorial and this piece of code makes me confused.

```
var str = '1' 
var str2:number = <number> <any> str   //str is now of type number 
console.log(typeof(str2))

log: String
```

As far as I understand, str was inferred as String in the first place, then it was asserted to be number while assigning it to str2. Str2 was defined as number. So why str and str2 are not both type number since one is converted to be number and the other is declared number?

Comment: For the same reason that if you do `var a = 1; var b = a + 1;` then `b` is 2 but `a` is still 1. Type assertion is something you do to an expression, it does not change the type of an existing variable.

Comment: TS type assertion only tell the compiler about the type. so it helps developer to use the variable properly. it does not convert the data type. so console log obviously show it is string.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking why the log shows `string` at runtime, or are you asking why the variable `str` doesn't have type `number` at compile-time?

Comment: Im actually more confused about type of str2 being String. Can I say that, the type annotations are just ways for the compiler to check if semantics are right, it does not care about what types the underlying values actually are, and won't do anything about it?

Comment: off-note: `str2` is not `String` - the latter is the boxed object-like value (and corresponding type) that you can get with `new String("value here")`. Although you will likely not use it, it is important to distinguish between them.

Comment: also, `typeof` is JS "runtime" operator *and* TypeScript's compile-time operator. In your case it is the former, hence the type of `str2` being logged as `"string"`. Also, the tutorial uses the more obscure notation, but the `<number><any>` is the same as `as any as number`, the technique used to "safely" "cast" to another type (nowadays it is preferred to use `as unknown as number`, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript type assertion does **not** convert the *value* of the expression. It only tells the TypeScript compiler to think it is a specific type. When you look at the compiled code, you won't find `number` anywhere. That is the reason why it doesn't behave as you expect. If you want to convert the value to a number, you have to use the `parseInt` function:

```js
var str = '1' 
var str2:number = parseInt(str)   //str value is now a number 
console.log(typeof(str2))

log: Number
```

Comment: I think the question is about types, not values; OP is asking why the variable `str` doesn't have type `number` after the type assertion.

Comment: Yeah, I explained it.